# Post a not empty file to Dspace with Curl

Tags: json, yii2, postman, php-curl, dspace

I am posting a file to dspace through dspace api, I am doing this with an action in php. With postman I send a form-data with the file, filename, bitstream id and token.

[image]

I am getting the temp file path with $_FILES and sending it by postfields curl option, but the file uploads empty, or with weird data, without its content.

```
public function actionSubirBitstream()
    {
        if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
            $body = $_POST;

            $prefijo = '/rest/items/';
            $host = ConfiguracionDspace::find()->where("clave='host'")->one()->valor;
            $puerto = ConfiguracionDspace::find()->where("clave='puerto'")->one()->valor;

            $token = $body['token'];
            $id = $body['id'];
            $final = '/bitstreams';

            $name = $body['name'];//nombre del archivo sin espacios
            $params = "?name=$name";
            $url = $host . ':' . $puerto . $prefijo . $id . $final . $params;

            $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
            //$path = $body['path'];
            //$file = new CURLFILE("$path");

            $headers = array("Content-Type: application/json", 'Accept: application/json', "rest-dspace-token: " . $token);

            $curl = curl_init($url);
            $options = array(
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('file'=> $file,'name' => $name),
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers
            );

            curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);
            $response = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
            return $response;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the \yii\web\UploadedFile for file retrieval?

Comment: I haven't tried, but I don't have a model created, so I just wanted to do it with $_FILES, I only need the file path I think, but this is not working right

Comment: I think the information on $_FILES holds more info in Yii2. Here, have a look at the UploadedFile implementation of loadFiles: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/6cba80d8878293b28913ed322766e34dcd82c5bf/framework/web/UploadedFile.php#L242

Comment: I only needed the temporal path of the file, that's what I get from ```$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];``` Thanks any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already post the file by the $_FILE variable, But what I needed to do was to use CURLFILE to create a new file, and give it the temp path of the file in the server
 `$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];`
and this in the postfields
`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('file'=> new CURLFile("$file"),'name' => $name),`
Thanks for the help friends

Here the code:

```
public function actionSubirBitstream()
    {
        if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
            $body = $_POST;

            $prefijo = '/rest/items/';
            $host = ConfiguracionDspace::find()->where("clave='host'")->one()->valor;
            $puerto = ConfiguracionDspace::find()->where("clave='puerto'")->one()->valor;

            $token = $body['token'];
            $id = $body['id'];
            $final = '/bitstreams';

            $name = $body['name'];//nombre del archivo sin espacios
            $params = "?name=$name";
            $url = $host . ':' . $puerto . $prefijo . $id . $final . $params;

            $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

            //$path = $body['path'];
            //$file = new CURLFILE("$path");

            $headers = array("Content-Type: application/json", 'Accept: application/json', "rest-dspace-token: " . $token);

            $curl = curl_init($url);
            $options = array(
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('file'=> new CURLFile("$file"),'name' => $name),
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers
            );

            curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);
            $response = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
            return $response;
        }
    }
```

The posted files with the rigth size(finally)
[image]

The form data I send by Postman, no need to use the field path
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('photo'=> new CURLFILE('/C:/Users/pfile3.jpeg'),'name' => $name),
```

this is the example of uploading a file with form key as photo and another key name

in your screen shot you have id and token in form data but in code its not inside POSTFIELDS

**in postman you can generate equalent code of request in any language , try generating the PHP equalent code and see if it works:**

To do this just click code link under the request url after saving the request

[image]